# Debugging Python in VS code with simple command line (like: debug(function) )

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am used to debugging in RStudio. Using R I simply use the command:  debug(my_function), then run the code and automatically the script debugs at my_function.

Now I am using Python in VS Code, I see debugging is possible by setting breakpoints visually using the red dots. However I need to debug a function without actually knowing where this function is stated. So my question is can I debug a specific function in VS Code using a command?

I hope to use something like this command line -> debug(my_function)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks impossible for now, I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2238) on GitHub.

Maybe you can try to copy the function into an isolated python file to debug it for now.

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: @Jelle Jansen You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

They are called [**Function Breakpoints**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_function-breakpoints)

> A function breakpoint is created by pressing the + button in the BREAKPOINTS section header and entering the function name. Function breakpoints are shown with a red triangle in the BREAKPOINTS section.

Comment: This is a nice way to approach it!